# Apply python script to each commit in git history

Tags: python, git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have a python script that change some files in my repo. I want to rewrite history by applying script to each commit.

git filter-branch command works fine if I use shell command with it like

```
PS>git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo 123 > 123.txt' -- --all
```

But when I use python script, it only makes changes in current working directory without changing history

```
PS>git filter-branch --tree-filter 'py C:/Scripts/myscript.py' -- --all
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

I even changed script with simplest oneliner

```py
print("123", file=open("C:/MyRepo/123.txt", mode="w"))
```

It still doesn't work. What might be a problem?

Comment: `filter-branch`'s `tree-filter` runs in a temporary directory. If your script tries to use some *other* directory, such as the one where the project lives, it will not succeed. It must run in the directory that filter-branch has chosen, which will be the current directory of the Python script when it is invoked.

Comment: Thank you! I changed script to work with relative paths. It's working now ☺